# Easiest way to switch many files to RRS in Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with many thousands of files copied from a linux machine.  I would like to switch all files within a folder to RRS (Reduced Redundancy Storage).  How can I do this without deleting the files/objects and re-uploading them?

The AWS management console enables me to enable RRS for a folder, but this operation does not apply recursively to nested folders.  Therefore I would have to manually select this on hundreds of folders, which isn't scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Google finds http://www.bryceboe.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/convert_to_rrs.py, a Python script using [Boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/) (writing such a script would have been my original suggestion) that appears to do this.